# How do i draw on top of a chart in Matplotlib Finance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, mplfinance

I created a chart using [MPL Finance](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance), here is how i did it:

```
chart = mpf.plot(df, type='candle', figratio=(20,9), style="nightclouds", savefig='plottedCharts/TEST.png', volume=True)
```

Where `df` is my Pandas dataframe. I'm trying to add square dots to some important points on the chart, like this:

```
plt.scatter('2020-05-16 13:30', 9300, marker='s', c='b', s=1)
```

But when i try this, nothing appears on the chart. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  You call `mpf.make_addplot()`  (make additional plot data)

And pass the result from make_addplot into `mpf.plot()` using the **`addplot`** kwarg:

```py
ap = mpf.make_addplot(signal,type=scatter,marker='s',color='b')
mpf.plot(df, type='candle', figratio=(20,9), style="nightclouds",
         savefig='plottedCharts/TEST.png', volume=True, addplot=ap)
```

The variable **`signal`** is a list, series, or dataframe ***that is the same length as*** **`df`**.

Set `signal` to the appropriate price value *where you want the squares to appear*.  All other values of `signal` should be filled with `float('nan')` (to ensure that it is the same length as `df`).

You can see specific examples doing exactly what you want in the tutorial here: https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/addplot.ipynb